# What is the recipient of a disclosure called?

Tags: single-word-requests, software

I am working on a software application in which users have facts about themselves which they must disclose to their employer or to a regulatory body. We are pinning down terminology to use for the various aspects of the disclosure process.

In general, we have the concept of a "party" which identifies a unique entity -- possibly an individual, a firm, a regulatory body, etc. We are using "disclosing party" to refer to the user who discloses the fact, and "disclosure" to refer to the act of disclosing.

We need a good term to use for the party to which the facts are being disclosed.

I've consulted a variety of common English-language dictionaries (M-W, New OAD, American Heritage, Random House) and thesauruses (Roget's, Collins, Oxford), and so far I have the following under consideration (with reasons I'm not particularly happy with them in parentheses):

- Disclosee <strike>(not a real word)</strike>
- Recipient or Receiving Party (too general)
- Notified Party (implies past tense; the disclosure may not yet have occurred)
- Informed Party (also implies past tense; also potentially ambiguous meaning)

Example sentence (just following the rules!):

> "The _____ must approve or reject the disclosure."

Is there a word for this? I would accept a standalone noun, or an adjective to pair with "party."

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Requests to help name something (such as a party to a legal document) are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask]. You might want to look at the [law.se] site intro also. They might have better advice about how to name parties to a legal document.

Comment: Legal documents often use the method of first defining, then using. So if you said, "...the party to whom the disclosure is made, hereinafter referred to as *the recipient*" it wouldn't matter that outside of your document the term might be "too general".

Comment: @MετάEd thanks. Does my list of items on the table so far, with parenthetical explanations for why they're less than ideal, not count as "results of research"? I spent quite a bit of time perusing synonyms of words close to what I want and polling subject experts to come up with those. 

Does "naming something" include just trying to come up with the most appropriate English word or phrase for a thing? If it does, why is "single-word-requests" a tag here?.

I'm not dealing with parties to a legal document. They're participants in a workflow.

Comment: @Jim the output of this process may or may not conclude with the generation of a populated form which would be submitted to a government entity (arguably a "legal document"), but putting the definition there would put it after nearly all of the usages we care about.

Comment: What's lacking in the body of your post is the resources you consulted and a summary of what you found. Single word requests are fine if they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.

Comment: The bulleted list is a summary of what I found. I've edited the question to include the resources I consulted. Expert-level, interesting, and thought-provoking all seem quite subjective -- are these terms clarified somewhere? I searched this site before asking and came up empty; doesn't that make it unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**disclosee** is actually a word that is used, but it doesn't show up in every dictionary. Still, it has been used many times.

[A Dictionary of Modern Legal Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=35dZpfMmxqsC&pg=PA280&dq=%22disclosee%22+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi38LDOkZTOAhVm54MKHQlrCKkQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22disclosee%22%20dictionary&f=false)

[image]

[Garner's Dictionary of Legal Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=O1m1bI5vCooC&pg=PA281&dq=%22disclosee%22+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi38LDOkZTOAhVm54MKHQlrCKkQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22disclosee%22%20dictionary&f=false)

[image]

[The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style](https://books.google.com/books?id=z_VmtjAU01YC&pg=PA117&dq=%22disclosee%22+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi38LDOkZTOAhVm54MKHQlrCKkQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I checked several dictionaries, but none of those. :)

Comment: @JakeRobb ~ no problem, the thing about these types of words is that you can create your own words just by adding suffixes like -ee or -phile, and dictionaries won't usually add them unless they become widely used

Comment: Makes sense. I never thought to search Google Books; I'm guessing that's standard practice here. Now I know!

Comment: @JakeRobb ~ well not everyone does it. btw I'd appreciate it if you accepted this answer by clicking the checkmark above.

Comment: I plan to, assuming another more appealing answer doesn't show up soon. :)